# Without selecting an select id. Get value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the select option without clicking on select tag.

Jquery

```
    var sub = $('#xyz').option[value = 14]
    $('#test').text(sub)
```

other jquery code which i tried

```
 var sub = $('select[name="abc"] option[value= '14']');
 $('#test').text(sub)
```

HTML

```
<select name="abc" id="xyz">

<option value="12">Apple</option>

<option value="13">Banana</option>

<option value="14">PineApple</option>
</select>
<p id="test">This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$("#xyz option[value='14']").text()` to get the text of an option specifying it's value

here is example

```js
console.log($("#xyz option[value='14']").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="abc" id="xyz">

<option value="12">Apple</option>

<option value="13">Banana</option>

<option value="14">PineApple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to do, but the second code you tried is actually correct, once you replace '14' with "14", since your string **starts** with `'`:

```
var sub = $('select[name="abc"] option[value= "14"]');

$('#test').text(sub.text()) // PineApple
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this, it is very simple in plain vanilla Javascript.

```
xyz.querySelector(`option[value="14"]`).textContent
```

gets you the text value of the option with the `value` attribute of `14`.

```js
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  test.textContent = `${e.target.value} is ` +  xyz.querySelector(`option[value="${e.target.value}"]`).textContent;  
})
```

```html
<select name="abc" id="xyz">
  <option value="12">Apple</option>
  <option value="13">Banana</option>
  <option value="14">PineApple</option>
</select>
<input type="number" min="12" max="14" step="1" value="12" id="input" />

<p>The current value is: <span id="test"></span></p>
```

Comment: @epascarello It solves the problem OP stated. The question is not explicitly requiring jQuery, and it's also tagged [tag:javascript]. So please elaborate on how I missed to answer OP's question.

Comment: "I want to get the select option without clicking on select tag." And your demo snipplet does not work

Comment: It works. Just increase and decrease the input next to the select. It tells you which select option text matches that value as soon as you change it.

Comment: @connexo but this is not how OP want it.

Comment: It's an extended demonstration as of how to solve the inherent problem. And how do you know what exactly OP wants?

Answer (score 1):

I'm rusty at jQuery, but to do this in Vanilla JS you would

1. get the updateable content box, and the list of options
2. make a mappable array from the resulting list of options
3. filter to your desired option
4. update your content box

```js
const textBox = document.getElementById('test');
const options = document.querySelectorAll('#xyz option');

let option = Array.from(options, option => ({ value: Number(option.value), text: option.textContent}))
  .filter(entry => entry.value === 12)
  .pop();

textBox.textContent = `${option.value}: ${option.text}`;
```

```html
<select name="abc" id="xyz">

<option value="12">Apple</option>

<option value="13">Banana</option>

<option value="14">PineApple</option>
</select>
<p id="test">This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.</p>
```